# How to load classes from a .war file and use them?

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, war

I have a project that is generating a `.war` file as a build artifact.
I want to load this `.war` into the JVM so that I can parse the runtime annotations it contains, but I am having trouble with loading the classes.

I have the following snippet of code to fetch class names from a `JarFile`:

```java
public static Set<String> getClassNamesFromJarFile(JarFile jarFile) throws IOException {
    Set<String> classNames = new HashSet<>();
    Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry jarEntry = e.nextElement();
        if (jarEntry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            String className = jarEntry.getName()
                    .replace("/", ".");
            className = className.substring(0, className.length() - 6);
            classNames.add(className);
        }
    }
    return classNames;
}
```

And I use this snippet for getting the `JarFile`:

```java
protected static JarFile getJarFile(String jarFileUrl) throws IOException {
    try {
        return new JarFile(new URI(jarFileUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20")).getSchemeSpecificPart());
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        return new JarFile(jarFileUrl.substring("file:".length()));
    }
}
```

Then, on my main, I have the following code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String warpath = "C:\\User\\Me\\Desktop\\someWarFile.war";

    // Fetch JarFile
    JarFile jar = getJarFile("file:" + warpath);

    // Load .war into the JVM
    URL url = new File(warpath).toURI().toURL();
    URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(
            new URL[]{url},
            Object.class.getClassLoader()
    );

    // Get class names in the .war
    Set<String> classes = getClassNamesFromJarFile(jar);

    // Try to get classes from name
    for (String className : classes) {
        try {
            System.out.println("CLASS FOUND: " + className);
            Class<?> actualClass= Class.forName(className, true, child);
        } catch(Error | Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

For every class I get the output:

```
...
CLASS FOUND: WEB-INF.classes.com.some.company.project.state.ProjectStateProvider$1
ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/some/company/project/state/ProjectStateProvider$1 (wrong name: WEB-INF/classes/com/some/company/project/state/ProjectStateProvider$1)
CLASS FOUND: WEB-INF.classes.com.some.company.configuration.rest.JsonProvider
ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/some/company/configuration/rest/JsonProvider (wrong name: WEB-INF/classes/com/some/company/configuration/rest/JsonProvider)
...
```

I have tried removing the `WEB-INF.` and the `WEB-INF.classes.` prefixes from the className, I have also tried adding `.class` to the className and every combination of the previous solutions, but I just get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

How do I reference classes loaded from the `.war` like the `WEB-INF.classes.com.some.company.project.state.ProjectStateProvider$1` class for example?

Comment: Put your classes in a jar file and put the jar file in `/WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: @MauricePerry How do I do that?

Comment: Create a new jar artifact with all the java files, add it as a dependency to your war project, and to whatever other project that needs to use the classes

Comment: @MauricePerry unfortunately this is not an option for me. I also tried following this tutorial https://www.journaldev.com/1338/how-to-create-jar-from-java-classes but most classes failed as I was unable to package the dependencies into the final jar.

Comment: OK, if you want to use an `URLClassLoader` to load classes, you can do this with a URL of the type: `jar:file:C:\\User\\Me\\Desktop\\someWarFile.war!/WEB-INF/classes/`. If what you want is to list the classes in the war, you need to start at entry `WEB-INF/classes`, or filter the entries that start with ``WEB-INF/classes"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code now. It now finds the respective class file inside the .war file.

The problem that will arise now, is if you want to load a class that depends on other classes that have not yet been loaded.

So you can either

- interrupt loading there and search for that file (write a custom ClassLoader that first scans all jar/war files for .class files WITHOUT loading them)
- follow the loading order given in the .war file (don't know ad hoc where to find that, tho

Code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;

public class JarLoading {



    public static void main(final String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        final String fileName = "D:\\upload\\K4D-Prozesstafel.war";
        final File file = new File(fileName);
        reloadWar(file);
    }



    static private void reloadWar(final File pJarFile) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        System.out.println("JarLoading.reloadJar() " + pJarFile);
        final String defaultPattern = "jar:file:" + pJarFile + "!/WEB-INF/classes/";
        //      final URL oldURL = pJarFile.toURI().toURL();
        final URL newURL = new URL(defaultPattern);
        System.out.println("DP:\t" + defaultPattern);

        try (final URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { newURL }); //
                final JarFile file = new JarFile(pJarFile);) {

            final Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = file.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                final JarEntry jarEntry = entries.nextElement();
                if (!isClassFile(jarEntry)) {
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    final String id = getClassName(jarEntry);
                    System.out.println("Loading file " + id);
                    final Class<?> cls = classLoader.loadClass(id);
                    System.out.println("\tLoaded file: " + cls);
                } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                    System.out.println("\tFile not a class file: " + jarEntry.getName() + "\n\t\t" + e2);
                    return;
                }
            }

            //          if (plugin.isValid()) mPlugins.add(plugin);
        }
    }



    static private boolean isClassFile(final ZipEntry entry) {
        return !entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().endsWith(".class");
    }
    static private String getClassName(final ZipEntry entry) {
        String className = entry.getName().replace('/', '.'); // including ".class"
        className = className.substring(0, className.length() - ".class".length());
        className = className.replace("WEB-INF.classes.", "");
        return className;
    }
}
```

This now will probably lead to exceptions such as:

```
JarLoading.reloadJar() D:\upload\K4D-Prozesstafel.war
DP: jar:file:D:\upload\K4D-Prozesstafel.war!/WEB-INF/classes/
Loading file biz.k4d.gremienplaner.prozesstafel.cruds.BoxCRUD
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: biz/cbsoft/lib/jee/glassfish/io/crud/TemplateCRUD_BaseEntity
```

Because the class file `biz.k4d.gremienplaner.prozesstafel.cruds.BoxCRUD` gets loaded now, but it depends on a file from another jar, namely `biz/cbsoft/lib/jee/glassfish/io/crud/TemplateCRUD_BaseEntity`.

Comment: Still does not work for me, `classLoader.loadClass` throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. Are you loading your classes from a war file? Are they in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder?

Comment: Okay, I updated my code to fit your needs with the different internal war file address mapping.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've changed the `getClassNamesFromJarFile` method slightly:

```
public static Set<String> getClassNamesFromJarFile(
        JarFile file, String pfx, String sfx) {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    Enumeration<JarEntry> enm = file.entries();
    while (enm.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry e = enm.nextElement();
        String path = e.getName();
        if (path.startsWith(pfx) && path.endsWith(sfx)) {
            path = path.substring(pfx.length(), path.length()-sfx.length());
            path = path.replace('/', '.');
            result.add(path);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String warpath = "C:\\User\\Me\\Desktop\\someWarFile.war";

    // Fetch JarFile
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(warpath);

    // Load .war into the JVM
    URL url = new URL("jar:file:" + warpath + "!/WEB-INF/classes/");
    URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(
            new URL[]{url},
            Object.class.getClassLoader()
    );

    // Get class names in the .war
    Set<String> classes = getClassNamesFromJarFile(jar, "WEB-INF/classes/", ".class");

    // Try to get classes from name
    for (String className : classes) {
        try {
            System.out.println("CLASS FOUND: " + className);
            Class<?> actualClass= Class.forName(className, true, child);
        } catch(Error | Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Now the classes will not load if they depend on other classes not in the classpath. For instance, if the war contains jar files in WEB-INF/lib, you need to add them to the `URLClassLoader`. You should also make available the jar of the servlet API.